# Datastream to Mathematica

Tags: import, data, databases

I currently use data from Thomson Reuters Datastream. With an add-in in Excel, the data can be requested. Because I need to use the data in Mathematica, and I need to update the data frequently: Is it possible to extract data from Datastream directly into Mathematica (with an API) ?

Does anyone has experience/knowledge doing such a thing?

Comment: I don't understand completely what you are trying to do.  How does Excel come into the picture?  And can you include some links to this datasource or some documentation decribing the API that allows accessing it?  What sort of API is it?

Comment: The short answer is no unless you are prepared to tackle the TR apis, which are complex. See [here](https://customers.reuters.com/developer/apis_tech.aspx). If you really need automation, you can use NETLink to manipulate a running instance of Excel and control the DS plugin programmatically.

Comment: MATLAB can do this, though I have no experience with that. If you have it you can try using [MATLink](http://matlink.org/); if it works correctly that would entail much less work than trying to automate Excel.